# Forming SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

In my android app, I am getting a list of nearby restaurants from Google Place API.

But unfortunately, this list does not give menus of the restaurant.

I have `T_RESTAURANT` and `T_MENU` tables.

Lets say, I get 4 restaurants in the list returned by API, then how should I make my query to extract data.

If I do:
`SELECT name, votes, review FROM T_MENU WHERE restaurant_name = REST_NAME_1;`

and I have to fire this query for each of the restaurants i.e. `4 times in this case.`

Can anyone suggest me a good solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT name,
       votes,
       review
FROM   T_MENU
WHERE  restaurant_name 
     IN ( <four restaurant names comma separated> )
```

Comment: Thanks. One question again: Lets say I retrieve 'id's of all restaurants in an array (associative array in case of php). Then how can I use the associative array in my 'IN' clause.

Comment: @Chanchal - Sorry..no knowledge of php. May be you iterate through array & make comma separated string....not sure though....

Answer (score 0):

You can use "IN" keyword instead of "=".
A also suggest using restaurant ids instead of names.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select T.name, T.votes, T.review ,M.<menu_items> 
from  T_RESTAURANT R join T_MENU M
where R.restaurant_name=T.restaurant_name
```